# AWS API Gateway Reverse Http Proxy to SQS Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use AWS API Gateway as a reverse (forwarding) proxy to AWS SQS using the configuration as seen in the screenshots. I essentially want to send a REST request to the API Gateway which then gets forwarded directly to the SQS REST API and returns the response.

When I send a request to the gateway, I immediately get back

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
    <Error>
      <Type>Sender</Type>
      <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
      <Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.</Message>
      <Detail/>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>51c903b2-4da3-5d5e-a3b8-589ee72167de</RequestId>
  </ErrorResponse>
```

However, when I switch the request URL to SQS directly (`https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`) the request succeeds.

What am I missing?

```bash
curl --request POST 'https://my-api-gateway.com/sqs' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: <date>' \
--header 'X-Amz-Security-Token: <token>' \
--header 'Authorization: <auth>' \
--header 'Amz-Sdk-Invocation-Id: <invocation>' \
--header 'Amz-Sdk-Request: attempt=1; max=10' \
--header 'User-Agent: aws-sdk-go-v2/1.16.5 os/macos lang/go/1.18.3 md/GOOS/darwin md/GOARCH/arm64 api/sqs/1.18.6' \
--header 'Content-Length: 206' \
--data-urlencode 'Action=ReceiveMessage' \
--data-urlencode 'MaxNumberOfMessages=10' \
--data-urlencode 'QueueUrl=<my-queue-url>' \
--data-urlencode 'Version=2012-11-05' \
--data-urlencode 'WaitTimeSeconds=20'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The API gateway integration needs to have an invocation role attached to it. This IAM role must have SendMessage policy for your SQS, so that your API gateway integration has access to push data to your queue.

For this, first create an IAM role with this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:1234:your-queue-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now go to API Gateway > Manage Integrations > Select your integration > Edit > Add the ARN of the newly created IAM role in Invocation role field
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrLk1.png)